# C++11 Android vector of pointers push_back doesn't work with libstdc++

Tags: c++, c++11, android-ndk, libstdc++

The following code compiles fine when using STLPort:

```
std::vector<Engine::Screen::IOverlay*> Overlays;
auto TestOverlay=new Engine::Screen::Overlay();
Overlays.push_back(TestOverlay);
```

However when compiling with libstdc++ it's trying to use move constructor for some reason:

```
error : cannot bind 'Engine::Screen::IOverlay*' lvalue to 'Engine::Screen::IOverlay*&&' ...\android-ndk-r8\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\include\bits\move.h
```

This is a very basic example but this issue occurs through out the application for all local pointers when using push_back.

Error occurs in move.h:

```
template<typename _Tp>
inline typename std::remove_reference<_Tp>::type&&
move(_Tp&& __t)
{ return __t; }
```

Example 2 (Another basic test I wrote:)

```
class TestClass {};
auto TestInstance=new TestClass;
std::vector<TestClass*> TestVector;
TestVector.push_back(TestInstance);
```

I compiled with ndk r8: -std=c++11  -D__STDC_INT64__

Comment: Is it the *actual* code?

Comment: Yes. Posting these three lines produces the same error.

Comment: Move is incorrectly implemented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems there are two bugs in the compiler. First it incorrectly calls`push_back(T&&)` which then attempts to move the object, which is implemented incorrecty:

```
template<typename _Tp>
inline typename std::remove_reference<_Tp>::type&&
move(_Tp&& __t)
{ return __t; }
```

It should be implemented as:

```
template<class _Tp> 
typename remove_reference<_Tp>::type&&
move(_Tp&& __t) noexcept //noexcept should be here!
{
  return static_cast<typename remove_reference<_Tp>::type&&>(__t);
}
```

which means your compiler is showing up two bugs in this context:

- incorrect overload resolution, as it calls `push_back(T&&)`.
- incorrect implementation of `std::move`

which version of what compiler are you using?

Comment: Thanks, I've copied libstdc++ from NDK8d which seemed to fix the issue.

Comment: I'm afraid if that really solves the problem. Compiler not giving error, is **not** a sign of absence of bug. What if it still resolves to `push_back(T&&)` but `move` works correctly? That is even a bigger issue. You need to make sure that it doesn't call `push_back(T&&)` when you pass an lvalue to it.